# Matrix multiplication of function

Tags: expression-manipulation

Suppose I had a 2-by-2 matrix with each entry a function, e.g., `{{#1&,#2&},{#1 + #2 &, -#1 + #2 &}}` and a vector of functions, e.g.,`{#1,#2}`. How would I matrix multiply the two so that I would get something like `{#1^2+#2^2,#1^2+#2^2}`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Function`, and because it has attribute `HoldAll` we need to force evaluation inside:

```
Function[Evaluate@Simplify[{{#1, #2}, {#1 + #2, -#1 + #2}}.{#1, #2}]]
```

gives

> {#1^2 + #2^2, #1^2 + #2^2} &